# raquo symbol finishing string in mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to write a MySQL database export/import feature. It retrieves the DB and saves it as an .sql file on the server. When I try to reupload the database if there is a string that contains the symbol » or « it stop the string right there.

Adding to the problems is the issue that some of the data that containing those symbols are in serialized arrays so to do a find and replace could end up messing the array.  (any tips around this would also be great)

Im wondering is there any easy way around this.

Here is my import code...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/database-dump-test/';
$sql_filename = 'db.sql';
$sql_contents = file_get_contents($path.$sql_filename);

$sql_contents = explode('/*endofquery*/',$sql_contents);



$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'u';
$password = 'password';
$name = 'db';

$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $name);

foreach($sql_contents as $query){

       $result = $mysqli->query($query);


       if (!$result)

            echo $mysqli->error  . "\n <br><br>";

}
?>
```

What happens is that a string that contains "This is » a test" will only import "This is"

I tried escaping but that does nothing.

Im sure this happens with lots of other characters.

EDIT: I thought it was fine with the euro symbol but it seems not to be so I have removed that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape certain string values at export(!). Use mysqli::real_escape_string(). Look at this example:

```
$string = "This is » a test";
$escaped  = $mysqli->real_escape_string($string);

$mysqli->query("INSERT into myTable (myColumn) VALUES ('$escaped')"));
```

A full documentation can be found at http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php